# Wired R response

Tags: linux, r, ubuntu

When I type this in `R`:

```
i<-1
j<-0
y<-c()
d4<-rep(NA,2)
d4[i]<-42
d4[i+1]<-51
for(l in d4[i]:(d4[i+1]-1)){
        y[j<-j+1]<-l        
}
```

The bash returns this:

```
> 
> i<-1
> j<-0
> y<-0
> d4<-rep(NA,2)
> d4[i]<-42
> d4[i+1]<-51
> for(l in d4[i]:(d4[i+1]-1)){
+ y[j<-j+1]<-l
-l10n_info             -legend                -license               -loadedNamespaces      -log2
-labels                -length                -limitedLabels         -loadhistory           -logb
-labels.default        -length<-              -line                  -loadingNamespaceInfo  -logical
-lag                   -length<-.factor       -linearizeMlist        -loadings              -logLik
-lag.plot              -length.POSIXlt        -lines                 -loadMethod            -loglin
-languageEl            -letters               -lines.default         -loadNamespace         -longley
-languageEl<-          -levels                -list                  -local                 -lower.tri
-lapply                -levels<-              -list2env              -localeToCharset       -lowess
-layout                -levels.default        -list.dirs             -locator               -ls
-layout.show           -levels<-.factor       -list.files            -lockBinding           -ls.diag
-lazyLoad              -lfactorial            -listFromMethods       -lockEnvironment       -lsfit
-lazyLoadDBexec        -lgamma                -listFromMlist         -loess                 -lsf.str
-lazyLoadDBfetch       -lh                    -lm                    -loess.control         -ls.print
-lbeta                 -library               -lm.fit                -loess.smooth          -ls.str
-lchoose               -library.dynam         -lm.influence          -log                   -lynx
-lcm                   -library.dynam.unload  -lm.wfit               -log10                 
-ldeaths               -licence               -load                  -log1p                 
+ y[j<-j+1]<-l
+ }
>
```

`y` contains what it should, but what causes the blurb on the prompt and how to prevent it?

(if you replace `l` by `ww` the blurb deseapers)

Comment: I think your R is broken.

Comment: What are you trying to do there with `NULL[0 <- 0 + 1] <- 42` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is caused by the two tab characters that follow the body of `for` loop. What you see is simply R's attempt to complete the statement that You began typing:

```
y[j<-j+1]<-l[tab][tab]
```

Try to type just `-l` and press tab key two times - You will get the same result.